# Wordpress Metaboxes.php

Tags: php, wordpress, meta-boxes

I am new to this metaboxes.php file, where all the content for the wordpress takes place.

I have a section of Metaboxes.php

```
array(
    'args' => array(
        'post_type' => 'xx_property',
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'post_status' => array(
            'publish'
        ),
    ),
    'data' => 'posts',
    'id' => 'xx_realtor',
    'multi' => true,
    'title' => __( 'view', 'xx_posts' ),
    'type' => 'select',
),
```

Here, this is a select box and select all the realtor who has post_status as publish, but I need to see if the realtor is active or nor. that's in `id=xx_active`.

instead of `post_status`, I need to point this to saying if the realtor is active show the list.

Can anyone has any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Add new meta box for post as a realtor and set this value as active or inactive.

Refer below example code for custom meta box creation,

```
// Post offer box
 add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'post_offer' );
 function post_offer() {
     add_meta_box(
         'post_offer',
         __( 'Price', 'agrg' ),
         'post_offer_content',
         'post',
         'side',
         'high'
     );
 }

 function post_offer_content( $post ) {
   wp_nonce_field( 'myplugin_meta_boxeee', 'myplugin_meta_box_nonceeee' );
   $post_offer = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'post_offer', true );
   echo '<label for="post_offer"></label>';
   echo '<input type="text" id="post_offer" name="post_offer" 
   placeholder="'._e('Enter price here','agrg').'" value="';
   echo $post_offer;
   echo '">';

 }


 add_action( 'save_post', 'post_offer_save' );
 function post_offer_save( $post_id ) {
  global $post_offer;
  if ( ! isset( $_POST['myplugin_meta_box_nonceeee'] ) ) 
  {
    return;
  }
  if ( ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['myplugin_meta_box_nonceeee'], 'myplugin_meta_boxeee' ) ) 
  {
   return;
  }
  if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) {
   return;
  }

  if(isset($_POST["post_offer"]))
  $post_offer = $_POST['post_offer'];

  update_post_meta( $post_id, 'post_offer', $post_offer );
 }
```

Comment: close enough, but I am working on Redux extension and post_type and its post_details are programmed.. My code looks similar to this site.
https://docs.reduxframework.com/extensions/metaboxes/

Comment: @Krist All the best

Comment: the function is created in such a way that the any update/edit/add is done through the same function. and it is getting updated in the postmeta database.. 
or it is possible to edit the post_status using a condition?,

Comment: use post update hook and get the all values of post and check meta box value an then you can update post status anything you want. https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/post_updated